# Python Script to kill java process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python scripting, we are trying to kill multiple java processes using the python script.  Below is the script.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
 import os, signal

 def process():

     name = ['test1.jar','test2.jar','test3.jar']
     try:

            for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep " + name + " | grep -v grep"):
          fields = line.split()

          pid = fields[0]

          os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
      print("Process Successfully terminated")

      except:
      print("Error Encountered while running script")

 process()
```

We are not able to kill the process and end up with an "Error Encountered while running script" message.

Comment: Try: `except Exception as e:` new line `print(e)`

Comment: from what i can see, this script only kills processes. Why not just kill the process directly from the session that is used to call this python script ?